# Sobreescribir fichero en paquete CLICKONCE

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vb.net, clickonce

Tengo una aplicación que se apoya en un fichero .XML que contiene unas cadenas de texto para realizar una funcionalidad.
La aplicación la distribuyo por clickOnce, tengo la necesidad de sustituir el fichero .XML en el paquete clickOnce desplegado en el servidor, sin necesidad de desplegar todo el paquete, solo sustituir el fichero .XML, pero no lo consigo ¿Es posible?
He realizado un proyecto de test que me permita realizar pruebas  más ágilmente, pero hasta el momento no he encontrado ninguna solución, ni suscribiéndome a eventos clickOnce, ni con el mageUI, ni manejando las propiedades de publicación en la solución. Utilizo VS2019